# How to use multiple variables in pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

## How can I use multiple variables in my query:

```
import pymysql

def get_firstname(y):


db = pymysql.connect(host="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 
    user="xxxx",  
    passwd="xxxxx",     
    db="XXXXXXX")   

cur = db.cursor()

query = "SELECT first_name FROM information WHERE x = y;" 
cur.execute(query, (y))

result = str(cur.fetchone()[0])
return(result)

x = user_id
y = 1


print (get_firstname(y))
```

I would like to be able to change x to different variables, depending on my choice. Like user_id, last name, email etc. All columns in my database. #y is another variable which represent the value of the column in my database.

Ex1: if x is "user_id" and y is "1", then the result is the first name of the person with user_id 1.

Ex2: if x is "email" and y is "person@person.com", then the result is the first name of the person with the email person@person.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code:

```
import pymysql

def get_firstname(x, y):
    db = pymysql.connect(host='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
        port=3306,
        user='xxxx',  
        password='xxxxxxxx',     
        db='test_db')   

    cur = db.cursor()

    query = "SELECT first_name FROM `information` WHERE %s" %(x)
    final_query = query+"=%s"
    #print(final_query)
    cur.execute(final_query, (y,))

    result = cur.fetchall()
    return(result)

x = 'user_id'
y = 1

output = get_firstname(x,y)
if output:
    for x in output:
        print(x)[0]
```

***`Sample Inputs:`***

```
x = 'email_id'
y = 'xx@gmail.com'
```

or

```
x = 'user_id'
y = 1        // Not enclosed with single quotes
```

Comment: Thanks for comment.

Comment: Gave me another problem though.
I used it as 
x = 'last_name'
y = 'Larsen' 

I have several users with that last name, but it only shows the first user with this last name. Can it repeat the code until there isn't any more users in my database with that last name, and then print them all?

Comment: Glad the solution worked!. Kindly accept the answer(by marking the checkbox) if you found it helpful and if it answers your question so that, it will be useful for others in the community as well. Welcome to SO !

Comment: Know you done a lot - but realised if I'm able to change the "SELECT" statement, then the code is universal for all the look-up in the database, that I want to do. - Is this possible as well?

I'm trying to understand the changes you have done, but can completely figure out what the "isinstance" does.

Comment: Yes, further changing the `SELECT` statement is possible. It is just a matter of how flexible you need it to be.With the above code as template you can  parameterize whatever section of `SELECT` you need and that should be it. The `isinstance` method is used to check if the input is of type `string` so that it is enclosed with single-quotes for using in sql query.

Comment: The queries being used are open to SQL injection attacks. Kindly secure them before using in production.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil I didnt know it was production query. Anyway I updated the code to use `final_query` which gets passed to `cursor.execute()` not to use direct string substitution. Hope this is Ok.

Comment: The argument is not a sequence

Comment: Updated the argument to a sequence.

Comment: Just a code style suggestion: you could use `str.format()` in order to avoid having to form the query in 2 parts and stay readable (no %-escaping): `query = "SELECT first_name FROM information WHERE {column} = %s".format(column=x)`

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone